# Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous with $f(0)=f(1)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was thinking about the following problem:
Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous with $f(0)=f(1)=0.$Then which of the following is not possible?

> (a) $f([0,1])=\{0\},$
>
> (b) $f([0,1])=[0,1),$
>
> (c) $f([0,1])=[0,1],$
>
> (d) $f([0,1])=[-1/2,1/2].$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hint: The continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Continuous functions reach their max and min on a closed interval.

Comment: To show that an option *is* possible, the easiest way is to exhibit a continuous function with the given property. Can you show that some of these options are possible?

Comment: Right direction: (b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval containing 0.  Consider the function

$$f : x\mapsto\cases{
3ax, & if $0\le x\le \frac13$ \\
a + (3x-1)(b-a) & if $ \frac13\le x \le \frac23$ \\
(3-3x)b & if $ \frac23\le x \le 1$
}
$$

The graph of $f$ is a piecewise-linear zigzag which starts at $\langle0,0\rangle$, zigs down to $\langle\frac13, a\rangle$, zags up to $\langle \frac23, b\rangle$, and then zigs back down to $\langle 1, 0\rangle$.

So $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with range $[a,b]$, and $f(0)=f(1) = 0$.

Comment: I take it that $a\le0$ and $b\ge0$?

Comment: @david: Is that required anywhere? I don't think so. But  my informal description of the shape of the graph might be inaccurate.

Comment: If $0$ is in the range (or, maybe i'm missing something)...

Comment: @david Oh, I see your point. It can't have $f(0)=f(1)=0$ *and* a range of $[a,b]$ unless $0\in [a,b]$.  Yes, quite so.  I will edit the question appropriately. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

By the Extreme Value Theorem, any function that is continuous on a closed and bounded interval (in this case, $[0, 1]$) has a global maximum and minimum.

The interval $[0, 1)$ in (b) has $1$ as a least upper bound, but not as a local maximum, which contradicts the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joe Zeng. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$f(x)=0\;\;,\;\;f(x)=\sin \pi x\;....$$

Comment: also thought of that